# What Is Graphic Switching & Are There Reasons to Turn It Off?

Tags: graphics, system-settings, gpu

I was tinkering about in the System Preferences of my Macbook Pro yesterday, when I came across **"Automatic Graphic Switching"** within the Energy Saver pane as exemplied below:

[image]

What exactly is Graphic Switching, and are there any reasons or instances when it shouldn't be automatically enabled & switched off ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Graphics switching is where the integrated graphics is switched for the discrete graphics when more performance is required (and where performance is more important than battery life & heat output).

You can see the current graphics card that is enabled, and forcefully switch between the two, with [gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io).

[image]

- Integrated graphics should be used when you need battery life over performance (the Integrated Only option in gfxCardStatus can be used to force integrated graphics in circumstances where OS X believes that the discrete graphics is required).
- Discrete graphics should be used when you need performance over battery life (this is usually not required to be set manually with the Discrete Only option since OS X is happy to switch automatically).
- Dynamic Switching uses the default OS X graphics switching.

When 'Automatic graphics switching' is disabled in the Energy Saver system preference pane, only the discrete graphics is used.

Comment: I thought to determine which graphics card your mac is using you all you need to do is -  click the Apple Icon and select About This Mac. From the popup window select the More Info button. This will bring up a report window. Within the list it will say graphics followed by the graphics card you are using.

Comment: Yes, but this is slow and annoying to quickly check. gfxCardStatus adds a menu bar item that you can use to check: the icon changes between **i** (Intel integrated) and **n** (NVIDIA discrete). It also lets you forcefully change between graphics cards as I mentioned.

Comment: Ah I see, good to know :)